# Ubuntu 19.04 - Chromium causes desktop to slow down

Tags: chromium

I'm using Chromium on Ubuntu 19.04. when I have about 15 tabs open (with Google docs / sheets in some), the system itself becomes unresponsive (e.g. mouse pointer starts to judder / go slow, keyboard unresponsive, cannot switch away from Chromium).

Does anybody know of the causes of this? Any suggestions?

(It's on a Lenovo Yoga 520, i5, 8th Gen, 8GB RAM, so a reasonable spec, though obviously not top spec.)

Comment: Post the output of `top -n 1 -o %MEM | head -30` and `top -n 1 -o %CPU | head -30`. What extensions are you using? What does *menu (⋮) > More Tools > Task Manager* tell you?

Comment: Try disabling "hardware acceleration" in the Chromium if it is enabled.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting, that's very helpful. There aren't any major extensions. The swap was set to 1GB (default on new install), so I've set this to 8GB now. Hoping that's the cause. WIll try the other suggestions too!